# Почему в консоль падает ошибка при удалении элемента

Tags: javascript

Код:

```
........    
var imgBox = document.querySelector('.s-product_images');
var img = self.DOM.currentIMG.cloneNode(true);
img.classList.add('product_image--move');
imgBox.appendChild(img); // Здесь добавил
var imgCor = getOffsetRect(self.DOM.currentIMG);
var informerCor = getOffsetRect(informer);
img.style.top = informerCor.top - imgCor.top + 'px';
img.style.left = informerCor.left - imgCor.left + 'px'; // если поставить img.style.right ошибки нет.... причем тут это????? 
img.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
    imgBox.removeChild(img); // здесь удалил
});    
........
```

Текст ошибки:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The
>   node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Comment: Предположу, что эвент вызывается несколько раз.

Comment: попробуй заменить `img` на `this`: `imgBox.removeChild(this);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Событие `transitionend` будет срабатывать для каждого измененного свойства, которому прописан переход. Например, если вы изменяете свойства `top` и `left`, и свойство `transition-property` указано для каждого из них (или для всех), то событие `transitionend` сработает два раза, и во втором случае `img` уже не будет присутствовать среди потомков `imgBox`, о чем и говорит вам ошибка.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Пометил как правильный. Разобрался. Переделал через анимацию css.